# Stack Exchange Editor Extra: a userscript to add extra features to the Markdown Editor

Tags: script, greasemonkey, editing, tampermonkey

### Stack Exchange Editor Extra

A userscript which adds extra features to the default SE Markdown Editor.

Extra features:

- Insert *code* with Ace Editor (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>)
- Find & Replace (with modifiers) (<kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>f</kbd>)
- KBD-ify selected text (<kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>k</kbd>)
- Auto correct (very basic)
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> key indents rather than moves focus
- Side by side editing (for new questions/new answers only)
- Improved link insertion: auto search via DuckDuckGo allows you to easily link to popular websites
- Improved image insertion: add a smaller image with a link to a bigger one or just the plain image

### Usage

The image & link dialogs are simply replaced - clicking the normal icon will show the new one. For all other features, a small toolbar is added:

> [image: Toolbar]

### Install

- You'll need a userscript manager such as [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (for Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) (for Chrome).
- <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Extra/raw/master/SEEX.user.js)</kbd> or <kbd>[View source](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Extra/blob/master/SEEX.user.js)</kbd>
- I've only tested on Chrome so far...

### Feedback

Please post bugs or feature requests as Issues [at Github](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Extra). Pull requests are, of course, welcome! :) For bugs, please check whether there is anything in your browser's console to help in fixing it!

Comment: Install/view src links are broken.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere sorry about that, it's fixed now. (and sorry for the extreme delay!!) :)

Comment: OP appears to have stopped maintaining this - https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Extra/issues/1.