# Stack Exchange WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: script, greasemonkey, editing, tampermonkey

Markdown is *great!* But [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editors are really useful - no waste of screen space by having the preview underneath what you're typing, no accidents with markdown: **You see what you get!** So, I made a **WYSIWYG editor for Stack Exchange sites**.

It uses a HTML to Markdown converter [that I made](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101791/41415) (slightly modified after being reviewed at Code Review; thanks [@IsmaelMiguel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101843/41415)!) (which uses DOMParser()) and a contenteditable div.

As a result, it will only work on [browsers that support the contenteditable attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable), and also [DOMParser()](http://caniuse.com/#search=domparser).

It is in an **alpha stage and can break at any time.** But... *this post was written with the WYSIWYG editor! :)*. It is packaged as a userscript, but basically works like a Chrome extension (but I ain't paying to publish :P)

## Installation

1. Install Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey
2. Go to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shu8/SE-WYSIWYG-Editor) to [install](https://github.com/shu8/SE-WYSIWYG-Editor/raw/master/wysiwyg.user.js) or [view the source code](https://github.com/shu8/SE-WYSIWYG-Editor/blob/master/wysiwyg.user.js)
3. Enjoy

## Screenshots

[image]

## Notes

- Nothing from the standard screens has been removed - you will still see the default textarea (see [my answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6574/26088) for why)!
- **Please help by submitting issues and pull requests!**
- It only works for NEW questions and answers and the moment
- If you're interested, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pmld.png) of this finished post in the editor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Planned Features

- Dialog to upload images using imgur directly from the WYSIWYG editor (currently have to use SE's image button on the original editor!)
- Better design
- Better support for `<code>` tags
- Keyboard shortcuts for common buttons
- Adding features from my [Stack Exchange Editor Extra: a userscript to add extra features to the Markdown Editor](https://stackapps.com/q/6508/26088) userscript
- Get it to work for edits

## Known bugs

- `<code>` doesn't work very well

Answer (score 0):

I applaud your initiative in making a custom (and hopefully consensual) solution for WYSIWYG editing of posts.

Personally, I'd have tought that something like XenForo's [common forum](https://xenforo.com/solutions/#xf) solution might be a decent basis. 
Then add on things like MathML, LaTex and so on.